# boost::any копирует значение?

Tags: c++, boost

Почему не совпадает указатель на объект, если сначала его превратит в any, а потом обратно в тот-же тип?

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main() {
        int i = 1;
        int* p = &i;
        boost::any a = i;
        int i2 = boost::any_cast<int>(a);
        int* p2 = &i2;
        std::cout << p << " == " << p2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        *p = 2;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        *p2 = 3;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод:

```
[root@localhost Test]# make
=============================================
touch test
rm test
ccache -c
Cleaned cache
ccache g++ -c -Wall test.cpp -o test.o
ccache g++  test.o -o test
rm -r test.o
./test
0xbeb49740 == 0xbeb49748
1
2
2
```

Как можно этого избежать? Использовать как any сам указатель?

Comment: Если хотите, что бы в адрес не менялся - храните в any указатель: `boost::any a = &i; int& iref = *boost::any_cast<int*>(a)`

Answer (score 4):

При чем тут `any`?

Вот по сути ваш код:

```
    int i = ...;
    int* p = &i;
    int i2 = ...;
    int* p2 = &i2;
    std::cout << p << " == " << p2 << std::endl;
```

У вас две разные переменные, которые, конечно же, находятся в памяти в разных местах - так что их адреса, понятно, разные.

Comment: Тогда могу-ли я получить адрес первой переменной после конвертации в any и обратно? Или нужно будет конвертировать указатель?

Comment: Адрес переменной останется неизменным, что бы вы с ней не делали.